# cPanel API authentication methods

Tags: php, authentication, cpanel

I am trying to access the cPanel's API using the cpanel security token CPSESSXXXXXX, which I generate by using cPanel's LogMeIn class.

While I can generate the security token without any problem. I want to use that token to access the API. Is it possible? Or do we need to authenticate the user in every API call with their username and password?

Could anyone please help out over here.

Thanks